# why is my SERIALIZED JSON getting UN-SERIALIZED after it reaches a java script function parameter?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a java script function that gets executed on the page pre-render event:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var script = "<script>CreateProjectTree('" + serializedSearchCriteria + "');" + "</script>";
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof (string), "createProjectTree", script);
}
```

The variable that gets passed to the above java script function is a serialized JSON that gets populated on the `Page_Load` event:

```
serializedSearchCriteria = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProjectSearchCriteria);
```

This is the value of serializedSearchCriteria after it has been serialized:

```
{"QueryString":null,"ProjectName":"\"24\"","SeasonName":"","MemberName":"","CompanyName":"","CompanyRole":0,"CompanyRoles":"","Year":""}
```

You can see that serializing it successfully escapes the double quotes for the value `24`.

The issue here is that when I look at the java script function under debug mode, the value of the variable serializedSearchCriteria is now this:

```
{"QueryString":null,"ProjectName":""24"","SeasonName":"","MemberName":"","CompanyName":"","CompanyRole":0,"CompanyRoles":"","Year":""}"
```

Notice the `24` now. It isn't escaped anymore. Therefore, this object isn't a valid JSON anymore once it's inside the java script function.

Why is this happening?

The object should be coming in SERIALIZED ... at some point, it is getting un-serialized. Does anyone know why?

Comment: json serialize the json serialization and see what happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser evaluates the `script` element, it also parses your javascript, sees those backslashes and consumes them.  You need to escape the escapes.

If you really want to pass a JSON string to the `CreateProjectTree` function, sometimes the easiest way is to just re-serialize it instead of trying to insert it as a serialized string in your script:

```
var script = "<script>CreateProjectTree(JSON.stringify(" + serializedSearchCriteria + "));" + "</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it was parsed as a JavaScript string literal, where `\` is an escape character.

If you want to output a JavaScript string literal containing a JSON text, then you need to escape any special characters in it (i.e. whatever quote character you are using to delimit the string, and `\`s).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is being treated as a string, try:

```
var script = "<script>CreateProjectTree(JSON.parse('" + serializedSearchCriteria + "'));" + "</script>";
```

You will noticed the JSON.parse js function has been added.